# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint using Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, primary-key

I am having a problem with a `BULK INSERT` in the code below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubscribersDeliveries]
(
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [LimitReached] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IdSubscriber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContentType] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [UTCDate] [date] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_SubscribersDeliveries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([Status] ASC, [LimitReached] ASC, [IdSubscriber] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO dbo.SubscribersDeliveries 
                (IdSubscriber, 
                 Status, 
                 LimitReached, 
                 ContentType, 
                 UTCDate) 
    SELECT DISTINCT s.IdSubscriber, 
                    CASE cdoi.Status
                      WHEN 0 THEN 0 
                      WHEN 1 THEN 1 
                      WHEN 2 THEN 2 
                      WHEN 3 THEN 1 
                      WHEN 4 THEN 1 
                      WHEN 5 THEN 1 
                      WHEN 6 THEN 1 
                      WHEN 7 THEN 1 
                      WHEN 8 THEN 2 
                    END AS Status, 
                    CASE 
                      WHEN CONDITION1  THEN 1
                      WHEN CONDITION2 THEN 1
                      WHEN CONDITION3  THEN 1
                      ELSE 0 
                    END LimitReached, 
                    cam.ContentType, 
                    @Date
            FROM Tables join
```

Note that I'm using the `DISTINCT` clause. This script returns the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SubscribersDeliveries'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SubscribersDeliveries'.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

When tried to group by inside, throw me an error because need to group by also by cdoi.IdDeliveryStatus  and I need to group by the CASE result.

```
CASE cdoi.IdDeliveryStatus 
                     WHEN 0 THEN 0 
                     WHEN 1 THEN 1 
                     WHEN 2 THEN 2 
                     WHEN 3 THEN 1 
                     WHEN 4 THEN 1 
                     WHEN 5 THEN 1 
                     WHEN 6 THEN 1 
                     WHEN 7 THEN 1 
                     WHEN 8 THEN 2 
                   END                  AS IdDeliveryStatus
```

Now I've tried to encapsulate all the query

```
SELECT result.IdSubscriber, 
                result.IdDeliveryStatus, 
                result.LimitReached, 
                result.ContentType, 
                @Date 
FROM   (SELECT distinct s.IdSubscriber, 
               CASE cdoi.IdDeliveryStatus 
                 WHEN 0 THEN 0 
                 WHEN 1 THEN 1 
                 WHEN 2 THEN 2 
                 WHEN 3 THEN 1 
                 WHEN 4 THEN 1 
                 WHEN 5 THEN 1 
                 WHEN 6 THEN 1 
                 WHEN 7 THEN 1 
                 WHEN 8 THEN 2 
               END                  AS IdDeliveryStatus, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN cdoi.IdDeliveryStatus = 0 
                      AND u.Limit1 > 0 
                      AND ( ISNULL(s.Limit1, 0) + 1 >= u.Limit1) THEN 1
                 WHEN cdoi.IdDeliveryStatus IN ( 1, 3, 4, 5, 
                                                 6, 7 ) 
                      AND ( ISNULL(s.Limit1, 0) + 1 >= u.Limit1) THEN 1
                 WHEN cdoi.IdDeliveryStatus IN ( 2, 8 ) 
                      AND ( ISNULL(s.Limit2, 0) + 1 >= u.Limit2) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 
               END                  LimitReached, 
               cam.ContentType ContentType
        FROM   @tempCampaigns t 
               JOIN Campaign cam WITH (NOLOCK) 
                 ON t.idcampaign = cam.IdCampaign 
               JOIN DBO.Subscriber s WITH (NOLOCK) 
                 ON s.IdUser = cam.IdUser 
               JOIN DBO.[User] u WITH (NOLOCK) 
                 ON s.idUser = u.idUser 
               JOIN DBO.Deliveries cdoi WITH (NOLOCK) 
                 ON cdoi.IdSubscriber = s.IdSubscriber 
                    AND cam.IdCampaign = cdoi.IdCampaign 
        WHERE   s.IdSubscribersStatus < 3 
) result 
            GROUP BY result.IdSubscriber, 
                    result.IdDeliveryStatus, 
                    result.LimitReached, 
                    result.ContentType, 
                    result.IdSubscribersStatus
```

In the inside query use a DISTINCT, and in the outside, used de group by, but continue returning duplicated!!!

Comment: `distinct` operates on **all** columns in the select list. As your `select` contains more columns than the primary key has, duplicates can happen.

Comment: Can you show us the complete query? You'll need to add a `GROUP BY` clause in order to have unique IdSubscriber+Status+LimitReached.

Answer (score 1):

as already pointed out you can use that structure & query just adding a `group by` to the `select`.
your select query have to be modified as follows (just an example):

```
SELECT s.IdSubscriber, 
  CASE cdoi.Status
    WHEN 0 THEN 0 
    WHEN 1 THEN 1 
    WHEN 2 THEN 2 
    WHEN 3 THEN 1 
    WHEN 4 THEN 1 
    WHEN 5 THEN 1 
    WHEN 6 THEN 1 
    WHEN 7 THEN 1 
    WHEN 8 THEN 2 
  END AS Status, 
  CASE 
    WHEN CONDITION1  THEN 1
    WHEN CONDITION2 THEN 1
    WHEN CONDITION3  THEN 1
  ELSE 0 
  END LimitReached, 
  max(cam.ContentType), <----- here the change
  @Date
FROM Tables join
```

then you have to add the `GROUP BY` part:

```
GROUP BY s.IdSubscriber, 
      CASE cdoi.Status
        WHEN 0 THEN 0 
        WHEN 1 THEN 1 
        WHEN 2 THEN 2 
        WHEN 3 THEN 1 
        WHEN 4 THEN 1 
        WHEN 5 THEN 1 
        WHEN 6 THEN 1 
        WHEN 7 THEN 1 
        WHEN 8 THEN 2 
      END AS Status, 
      CASE 
        WHEN CONDITION1  THEN 1
        WHEN CONDITION2 THEN 1
        WHEN CONDITION3  THEN 1
      ELSE 0 
      END LimitReached
```

please note that the `max(cam.ContentType)` is just a suggestion and since you posted only part of the query the syntax must be carefully checked.
if no grouping is possible because of other constraints you have either to modify the constraints or modify the structure of the destination table.

a closing note: there is not enough information to make anything but a wild guess but in my opinion there is something to check in the table structure; perhaps the primary key have to be changed or the table name is misleading?

Answer (score 0):

All three columns , trying insert the same value like '1' in the above statement using case statement.

consider the case like

```
when
.
    [Status]=1 
    [LimitReached]=1 
    [IdSubscriber]=1
```

Comment: But I'm using a distinct clause on the select, this doesn't remove all the duplicated?